# Can't upload files more then 2 MB

Tags: php, apache, nginx

I have problem with uploading files more then 2 MB... System is Apache and Nginx. I try to change settings and use .htaccess in /tmp/ directory with same settings but nothing happened..

On server is installed modsecurity but Off :

```
SecRuleEngine Off 
SecResponseBodyAccess Off 
SecRequestBodyLimit 131072000 
SecRequestBodyNoFilesLimit 131072
SecRequestBodyInMemoryLimit 131072
```

Please help!

**/etc/php5/cli/php.ini and  /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini**

```
upload_max_filesize = 20M
post_max_size = 20M
max_execution_time = -1
max_input_time = 1800
memory_limit = -1
```

**/etc/nginx/nginx.conf**

```
client_max_body_size 0;
```

**/etc/apache2/apache2.conf**

```
 <Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
    LimitRequestBody 2147483647
</Directory>
```

**/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/domen.conf**

```
<Directory /home/newboards/sites/domen.ru/> 
AllowOverride All 
Require all granted 
LimitRequestBody 2147483647
</Directory>
```

Comment: Have you rebooted apache since you made these changes?

Comment: yes, service apache2 restart  and service nginx restart

Comment: `System is Apache and Nginx` Uh... two web servers?

Comment: Nginx is frontend, Apache is backend ;)

Comment: Nginx doesn't have any sort of mod php installed so uses fastCGI. Php's fastCGI process manager (fpm) uses a separate configuration which you probably also need to find and modify.

Comment: What exactly are the symptoms? The request gets rejected at what stage exactly? What do the logs of all involved systems (nginx, Apache, PHP) report?

Comment: I don't use fpm, it simple php-apache-nginx

Comment: just call a .php page with `phpinfo()` called and check the used php.ini file and the parameters you've changed

Comment: in /var/log/error.log is nix but sometimes is on screen 408 Request timeout, sometimes 413 Request Entity Too Large (nginx), but normaly 404 or sleep..  You can try here http://www.petsell.ru/load.php

Comment: It's not just uploading whatever you give it to your `/tmp/` dir is it?

Comment: in phpinfo is same: upload_max_filesize 20M, memory_limit -1, max_execution_time 0, post_max_size 20M   - I copied right now

Comment: petsell.ru/load.php  - here is just uploding for test, but normally it is posting and resizing via graphicmagic for ads with photos here http://www.petsell.ru/posting/

Comment: Might be wise to remove the link from the comments or anyone on the internet who sees this question might upload something to your `/tmp` directory...

Comment: On the my second server with debian 6 and without modsecurity is everething ok. Problem is in some settings in this server. May be problem with modsecurity. I try change #SecRuleEngine DetectionOnly to 
SecRuleEngine Off, but i suspect modsec may be work :)  Here is described a similar problem but by SecRuleEngine DetectionOnly. 
https://github.com/SpiderLabs/ModSecurity/issues/589

Comment: Thank you all for your help, everything was working after a reboot!  Sometimes apache2 restart and service nginx restart not enough to be completely happy